# How to get a scanner object into a reference variable?

Tags: java, object, arraylist

I cannot figure out how to format the code for my if-statements. Typically, I would take a string input from the user and use .equals, however the object I am required to use makes that impossible. Whenever I print the contents of the array, I get references. I want to get a user input stored to be stored in the array and printed in a later line of code.

Question: If possible, how do I get a scanner input to be assigned to a "Team" and referenced for comparison in the if-statements? How should I go about assigning these values?

Here is the code I was given

```
public class Team implements Comparable<Team> {

public String toString(String team, int wins) {
    String winningStatement = team + ": " + wins;
    return winningStatement;
}

// Data fields
private String name;
private int winCount;

Team() {
    name = "Sooners";
    winCount = 1;
}

Team(String inputName) {
    name = inputName;
    winCount = 1;
}

Team(String inputName, int inputWinCount) {
    name = inputName;
    winCount = inputWinCount;
}
```

Here is my attempt at using an ArrayList

```
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random rando = new Random();
        String name = "hi";
        int cycles = 0;
        int value = 0;
        ArrayList<Team> teams = new ArrayList<Team>();
        Team myTeam = new Team();
        System.out.println("Welcome to the Advanced Sportsball Tracker!");

        while (!name.equals("x")) // looping print statement
        { // x loop begins
            System.out.println("Which team just won? (x to exit)");
            name = scnr.next();
                if (!teams.equals(name))
                    {
                    teams.add(thisTeam);
                    myTeam.setWinCount(1);
                    }
                else if (teams.equals(name))
                {
                    myTeam.incrementWinCount();
                }
            cycles++;
        }// x loop ends
```

Thank you for the assistance

Comment: Why does the "overloaded constructor" matter to an "array list"? ArrayList does not call constructors. Remove unnecessary/unrelated information; when diagnosis problems and soliciting help.

Comment: Sorry, no idea what you're asking.  I don't see any `for` loop here, and I don't understand what you think is wrong.  The only thing I can see is that your `if` condition seems to be comparing a list to a string, which is never going to end well.

Comment: Then I am more confused about the nature of constructors. Was I given an object or class type "Team" that has a specific format like (int x, string y) or can I assign objects with any primitives values (int 10) to a "team" object?

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity I learned both of these concepts today and I have been getting them confused.

Comment: Yes, because you don't  know the terminology, your question doesn't make a whole lot of sense.  I would recommend finding a book or a tutorial and working through it.  You could come back to Stack Overflow if you have a specific question, once you know the right words to ask your question coherently.  Sorry to be so harsh, but it's very hard to help you without actually being able to understand what you're trying to ask.

Comment: It is not clear from your example what it is that you are confused about.  If you are new to two new concepts, then try starting with one and move to the next when the first concept is mastered.

Comment: After doing some more research, I understand that the object "Team" I am required to work with is not able to take printer inputs. So, I need to figure out a way to assign a print into to a Team object and compare that in the if statements.

Answer (score 0):

Judging only by the intent of your example... it appears that this is what you are trying to achieve.  As stated though, your question of how ArrayList objects relate to overloaded constructors does not really make sense

```
public class Team  {
    // Data fields
    private String name;
    private int winCount;

    public Team() {
        name = "Sooners";
        winCount = 1;
    }

    public Team(String inputName) {
        name = inputName;
        winCount = 1;
    }

    Team(String inputName, int inputWinCount) {
        name = inputName;
        winCount = inputWinCount;
    }

    public String toString(String team, int wins) {
        return team + ": " + wins;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getWinCount() {
        return winCount;
    }

    public void setWinCount(int winCount) {
        this.winCount = winCount;
    }

    void incrementWinCount() {
        winCount++;
    }
}

void runSystem() {
    List<Team> teams = new ArrayList<>();
    Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
    int cycles = 0;

    System.out.println("Welcome to the Advanced Sportsball Tracker!");

    System.out.println("Which team just won? (x to exit)");
    String name = scnr.next();

    while (!"x".equals(name)) {
        final String teamName = name;
        Team team = teams.stream().filter(t -> teamName.equals(t.getName())).findAny().orElse(null);

        if (team == null) {
            team = new Team(teamName, 1);
            teams.add(team);
        }
        else {
            team.incrementWinCount();
        }

        cycles++;
        System.out.println("Which team just won? (x to exit)");
        name = scnr.next();
    }
}
```